# React Testing Library Submits Form Even if Required Inputs are Empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, jestjs, react-testing-library

## Problem

If required Inputs are empty on the form, submit button shouldn't work. This is the nature of it when the user physically interacts with it.
But in the testing environment, the button submits without checking the form for required Inputs. This is the case when using "Simulate.click" or "fireEvent.click". I have found other forms talking about this issue, but haven't found a solution to it.
Thanks.

## Code

```
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name<span className="optional">*</span> 
            </label>
            <input
                className="contact-input"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={handleChange("name")}
                required
            />

            <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
```

## Test

```
test("When form is empty, expect submit to not work", () => {
const history = createMemoryHistory();

render(
    <Router>
        <Contact location={history}/>
    </Router>
)

const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', /send/i)

    // Both Simulate and fireEvent give the same results. 
    Simulate.click(submitButton)
    // fireEvent.click(submitButton)

    screen.debug()
    // I can see the form submitted and the "thank you" Html element is loaded. This should not be the case as required input wasn't filled. 
});
```

Comment: What happens when you physically click the button?

Comment: You aren't actually testing for anything: there's nothing being asserted in the test and nothing to cause the test to potentially throw an error and fail (unless `handleSubmit` throws an exception and crashes your React app ).

Comment: If' I physically click, it works properly. This problem only happens in a testing environment.

Comment: I didn't include the assertion. But for example, say if I include "sceen.debug()", I see that the form submitted and the "thank you" Html message element is loaded.

Comment: What is `name`? Depending on its value, your form could be valid

Comment: Could be related to this issue https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2898

Comment: It's exactly related to that issue.

Comment: name is an empty value. The Form works properly when manually testing it. Just not in a React Testing Library setting.